# error when requiring guidebox api for composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to install guidebox api on my server. I run the command: composer require guidebox/guidebox-php per the directions on the website and I get this error message:

```
Using version ^1.0 for guidebox/guidebox-php
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- guidebox/guidebox-php 1.0.0 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.2, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9].
- guidebox/guidebox-php 1.0.1 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.2, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9].
- guidebox/guidebox-php 1.0.2 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.2, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9].
- guidebox/guidebox-php 1.0.3 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.2, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9].
- guidebox/guidebox-php 1.0.4 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.2, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9].
- guidebox/guidebox-php 1.0.5 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.2, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9].
- guidebox/guidebox-php 1.0.6 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.2, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9].
- phpunit/phpunit 5.7.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.7.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.7.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.7.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.7.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.7.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.7.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.7.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.7.14 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.7.13 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.7.12 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.7.11 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.7.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.7.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.7.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.6.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.6.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.6.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.6.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.6.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.6.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.6.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.6.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.6.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.5.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.5.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.5.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.5.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.5.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.5.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.5.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.5.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.3.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.3.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.3.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.3.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.3.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.3.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.12 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.11 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- Installation request for guidebox/guidebox-php ^1.0 -> satisfiable by guidebox/guidebox-php[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
 You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used        by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I am running ubuntu server with php7 installed in fact I reinstalled it. I am very new to composer and php so please keep that in mind when answering.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have dom extension not installed on your system. PHPUnit needs it. So type the below command to install dom extension for php7.0

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

Hope, this helps.
check this discussion, if interested https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/how-do-i-install-the-dom-extension-for-php7